# Namespace e PDO = Erro

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, namespace

Estou fazendo uma Framework, usando namespaces. Porém no arquivo de conexão PDO está acontecendo um erro estranho para mim:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not
>   find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\Core\Controller.php:36
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\Core\Controller.php(36):
>   PDO->__construct('DB_TYPE:host=DB...', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\Core\Controller.php(20):
>   Application\Core\Controller->openDatabaseConnection() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Public\index.php(9):
>   Application\Core\Controller->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\Core\Controller.php on line 36

Index:

```
<?php

define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once 'autoload.php';

use Application\Core\Application;
use Application\Core\Controller;

$controller = new Controller;
```

Autoload:

```
function __autoload($class) {
$class = ROOT . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class). '.php';
if(!file_exists($class)) {
    throw new Exception("File path '{$class}' not found.");
} else {
    require $class;
}
}
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace Application\Core;
use PDO;

class Controller
{
/**
 * @var null Database Connection
 */
public $db = null;
/**
 * @var null Model
 */
public $model = null;
/**
 * Whenever controller is created, open a database connection too and load "the model".
 */
function __construct()
{
    $this->openDatabaseConnection();
    $this->loadModel();
    echo 'Loaded Controller <br/>';
}
/**
 * Open the database connection with the credentials from application/config/config.php
 */
private function openDatabaseConnection()
{
    // set the (optional) options of the PDO connection. in this case, we set the fetch mode to
    // "objects", which means all results will be objects, like this: $result->user_name !
    // For example, fetch mode FETCH_ASSOC would return results like this: $result["user_name] !
    // @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
    $options = array(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ, \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    // generate a database connection, using the PDO connector
    // @see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
    $this->db = new \PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
}
/**
 * Loads the "model".
 * @return object model
 */
public function loadModel()
{
    require APP . 'model/model.php';
    // create new "model" (and pass the database connection)
    $this->model = new Model($this->db);
}
}
```

Comment: A linha 32 parece ser a variável `$options...`, faltou a `'\'` contra-barra.

Comment: Ou add abaixo do namespace, use PDO;

Comment: Alterei o code mas agora está com outro erro.

Comment: No use coloque "use \PDO";

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Só uma correção no `código`, coloque a instancia da `PDO` dentro do bloco `try/catch`

```
try {
                    
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
                    
}
```

**Trecho do código**

```
private function openDatabaseConnection()
{
    
    try {
        
        // set the (optional) options of the PDO connection. in this case, we set the fetch mode to
        // "objects", which means all results will be objects, like this: $result->user_name !
        // For example, fetch mode FETCH_ASSOC would return results like this: $result["user_name] !
        // @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
        $options = array(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ, \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        // generate a database connection, using the PDO connector
        // @see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
        $this->db = new \PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    
                
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        
        echo 'Error:'. $e->getMessage();
        
    }
    
}
```

Para usar funções nativas com chamada em namespace, use um contra barra antes da do nome da classe ou função, ou faça a importação utilizando o operador [use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Exemplo:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Core;

use \PDO;
use PDOException;

//outras Exceptions
use Exception;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class Controller
{
   ...
```

Ou use `contra barra \` dentro dos `métodos`

**Final**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Core;

use \PDO;
use PDOException;

class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var null Database Connection
     */
    public $db = null;
    /**
     * @var null Model
     */
    public $model = null;
    /**
     * Whenever controller is created, open a database connection too and load "the model".
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->openDatabaseConnection();
        $this->loadModel();
        echo 'Loaded Controller <br/>';
    }
    /**
     * Open the database connection with the credentials from application/config/config.php
     */
    private function openDatabaseConnection()
    {
        
        try {
            
            $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            $this->db = new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);        
                    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            
            echo 'Error:'. $e->getMessage();
            
        }
        
    }
    /**
     * Loads the "model".
     * @return object model
     */
    public function loadModel()
    {
        require APP . 'model/model.php';
        // create new "model" (and pass the database connection)
        $this->model = new Model($this->db);
    }
}
```