# Classe Build-in do PHP não funciona no CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou tentando usar uma classe `Built-in` do `PHP` dentro do CakePHP porém é retornado um:

> Error: Class 'App\Controller\Component\DateTime' not found

**Onde esta sendo usado:**

```
public function listNewBanners($newBannersQuantity)
{
    $newBanners = TableRegistry::get('new_banners');
    $query = $newBanners->find();
    $query->select(['path_banner', 'date_start', 'date_end'])
        ->where(['date_start <' => new DateTime('today')])
        ->limit($newBannersQuantity);
    return $query;
}
```

Link da documentação oficial onde vi esta classe sendo usada: [Documentação](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)

Comment: Tente colocar uma barra antes, `new \DateTime('today')`

Comment: @rray Bruxo.... submeta uma resposta, sempre que quiser usar uma classe built-in devo usar esta \ ?

Comment: É o mesmo problema de [Namespace e PDO = Erro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67773/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para chamar classes nativas do php dentro de um namespace é necessário adicionar uma barra(`\`) antes do nome, dessa forma o php sabe que precisa chamar um classe/função do *core* e não uma com o mesmo nome que pode estar dentro do namespace atual.

Mude:

```
new DateTime('today')
```

Para:

```
new \DateTime('today')
```

Exemplo, sem a barra ou seja vai tentar chamar a classe do namespace atual se ela existir ou retornará `nome da classe not found`

```
<?php

namespace teste;

class Teste{
    public function __construct(){
         echo '<pre>';
         var_dump(new DateTime());
    }
}

class DateTime{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'minha DateTime personalizada';
    }
}

new Teste();
```

Saída:

```
minha classe personalizada
object(teste\DateTime)[2]
```

Exemplo com a barra que indica que essa classe é do *core*

Alteração:

```
class Teste{
    public function __construct(){
         echo '<pre>';
         var_dump(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2015-07-30 20:02:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
```

Comment: Também pode declarar `use DateTime` logo após `namespace teste`. Uso essa alternativa como convenção para o uso de classes nativas.