# Forma correta de usar a função abs do php

Tags: php

Galera qual a forma correta de usar esta função?

1º :

```
$limite = \abs($resultado_cadastro->limite);
```

2º:

```
$limite = abs($resultado_cadastro->limite);
```

Ambas funcionam, porem o netbeans fala que a correta é `\abs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php), ambas as formas são válidas.

O que acontece é que se a função que você está usando não for encontrada no *namespace* atual, haverá um fallback para o *namespace* global.

Dica: você pode usar primeira forma para discriminar a função própria do PHP caso escreva a sua própria versão daquela função. Por exemplo:

```
function strlen($str)
{
    return \strlen($str) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Você fala que com a \ haverá um fallback?

Comment: Sem a barra, caso a função não exista no namespace atual. Se houver a barra, você está forçando o uso da função presente no namespace global.

Comment: entendi, bom acho melhor deixar com a barra então ;) obrigado

Answer (score 3):

As duas formas estão corretas, no entanto deve-se usar a barra antes do nome da função ou classe quando estiver usando namespaces isso serve para todas as funções/classes do core do php, do contario o php tentará encontar um função chamada `abs()` no namespace atual e como não existe gera um erro, como nessa [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77473/91).

Answer (score 2):

Use o que está descrito no [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.abs.php) assim será garantido que independente das configurações da maquina todo o seu código irá funcionar de forma correta. Geralmente a "\" é usada quando você está fazendo o uso de um namespace ou uma classe.

Answer (score -2):

Da uma olhada na documentação amigo

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.abs.php