# Erro na listagem com PDO

Tags: php

Estou tentando aprender `PDO` mas estou tendo dificuldades.

Tenho 3 arquivos:

**Planos.php**

```
<?php

  namespace PLANOS;

  use BASE\Base;

  require_once "Base.php";

  class Planos extends Base {     

      public function __construct ($_conexao, $_tabela) {

         parent::__construct ($_conexao, $_tabela);

     }

  }

?>
```

**Base.php**

```
<?php

 namespace BASE;

 abstract class Base {

     private $conexao;  
     private $tabela; 
     private $ultimoCadastrado;

     public function __construct($_conexao, $_tabela) {

         $this->conexao = $_conexao;

         $this->tabela = $_tabela;

     }

     public function cadastrar (array $objeto) {

         $parametros = $valores = "";

         foreach ($objeto as $objeto=>$valor):

           $parametros.= $objeto.",";        
           $valores.= "'".$valor."',";

         endforeach;     

         $parametros = substr($parametros,0, -1);
         $valores = substr($valores,0, -1);

         $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->tabela." (".$parametros.") VALUES (".$valores.")";

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

         $execucao = $query->execute();

         $this->ultimoCadastrado = $this->conexao->lastInsertId();

         return $execucao;


     }

     public function ultimoIdCadastrado () {    

         return $this->ultimoCadastrado;

     }


     public function editar (array $objeto, $id) {

         $str = "";

         foreach ($objeto as $objeto=>$valor):

           $str .= $objeto ."='". $valor."',";       

         endforeach;

         $str = substr($str, 0, -1);

         $sql = "UPDATE ".$this->tabela." SET ".$str." WHERE id".ucfirst($this->tabela)."=".$id;

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

         return $query->execute();

     }

     public function bloquear ($id, $bloqueado) {        

         $sql = "UPDATE ".$this->tabela." SET bloqueado = '".$bloqueado."' WHERE id".$this->tabela." = ".$id;

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

         return $query->execute();


     }

     public function excluir ($id) {         

         $sql = "DELETE FROM ".$this->tabela." WHERE id".$this->tabela." = ".$id;

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);        

         return $query->execute(); 

     }

     public function listar () {

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tabela;

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

         $query->execute();

         return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

     }

     public function listarId ($id = null) {

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tabela;

         if ($id != null) $sql .= " WHERE id".ucfirst($this->tabela)."=".$id;

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

         $query->execute();

         return $query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

     }

     public function listarParametros ($where) {

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tabela." ".$where;

         $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

         $query->execute();

         return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

     }

 }

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php 

  ini_set("display_errors",true);
  ini_set("display_startup_erros",1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);

  use PLANOS\Planos;

  $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=funeraria2', 'root', 'mysql');

  $objeto = array (

      "tipo" => 's',
      "nome" => "Carlos",
      "login" => "caca",
      "senha" => "1234",
      "bloqueado" => "n"

  ); 

  $objeto2 = array (
      "idAdministradores" => 3,
      "tipo" => 's',
      "nome" => "Castro",
      "login" => "abcd",
      "senha" => "4321",
      "bloqueado" => "s"    
  ); 

  require_once "Planos.php";

  $planos = new Planos($conexao, "administradores");
//  echo $planos->cadastrar($objeto) ? 1 : 2;
//  echo "<br />";
  echo $planos->ultimoIdCadastrado();
  echo "<br />";
  echo $planos->editar($objeto2, 3) ? 1 : 2;
  echo "<br />";
  echo $planos->bloquear(3, 's') ? 1 : 2;
  echo "<br />";
  echo $planos->excluir(4) ? 1 : 2;
  echo "<br />";


print "<pre>";
print_r($planos->listar());
print_r($planos->listarId(1));
foreach ($planos->listarParametros("WHERE nome = 'Carlos'") as $admin):
  print_r($admin);
endforeach;
print "</pre>";

?>
```

Quando rodo esse `script` recebo o **erro** abaixo:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'BASE\PDO' not found in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\crud\Base.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\crud\index.php(47): BASE\Base->listar()
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\crud\Base.php on line 102
```

Mas não consigo achar que erro é esse!

A dúvida é que só não está fazendo leitura.

Porém gravação, exclusão, edição, normal!

Comment: Já tentou importar `use \PDO;` no arquivo *Tabelas.php* ?

Comment: Ou simplesmente coloque uma barra invertida ( \ ) em `return $query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );` ... `return $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Namespace e PDO = Erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67773/namespace-e-pdo-erro)

Comment: mas poque as outras operações como inserção, deleção e update dão certo. Apenas o select não dá?

Comment: Então, use PDO; na classe abstrata resolveu. Mas ainda fica a dúvida. Porque apenas para s SELECT? porque não também para UPDATE, DELETE e INSERT?

Comment: Porque é o único que você esta usando diretamente `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, a resposta da pergunta que marquei como duplicata.

Comment: Então, mas a minha conexão já é feita por PDO. Então, não seria seria o caso de precisar também de fazer use PDO na classe Tabelas? Senão, porque? Pode postar como resposta que eu marco ela como aceite!

Comment: Veja: [Namespaces e Use quando usar e para que servem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151487/), [Como funciona namespaces no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104420), [Para que serve realmente namespace?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195742)

Answer (score 3):

Você deve indicar que está usando uma classe nativa do PHP usando \ antes do PDO deixando assim:

```
new \PDO();
```

e

```
 return $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

Acho que isso deve resolver os seus problemas. Se não resolver me mande o erro que o PHP esta retornando com as alterações que eu falei.

Comment: Oi, isso já havia resolvido. O que eu gostaria de saber é porque apenas com SELECT deu isso? Com UPDATE, DELETE e INSERT não foi preciso fazer use PDO

Comment: É por que com o SELECT você solicita um retorno para a classe  "return $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );" já nos outros você tem um retorno predefinido.

Comment: Entedeu agora o porque o SELECT deu problema?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem. Veja. Olhe o método cadastrar, ultima linha: return $execucao;. Iso não é pedir retorno ao método? Acho que ainda estou meio confuso. Mas acxho que vou conseguir entender depois dessa tua outra resposta!

Comment: No exemplo que você deu do return $execucao o método retorna somente True ou false, já no select ele retorna ou array, ou em objetos e etc.. de certa forma você precisa informar o formato que o php vai retornar à sua consulta. que no caso seria colocando por exemplo \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC para ele retorna a consulta na forma de array.

Comment: hum, mas sem o \ ele já está retornando em forma de array. Não? Pelo menos é o que aparece no print_r(). Resolvi o problema apenas  colocando use PDO na classe de tabelas. Mas ainda estou com essa dúvida cruel!

Comment: Ele retorna por que isso default dele, você nem precisava ter colocado o  \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC dentro da função.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78972/discussion-between-dudut-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: Não está dando certo o chat para mim.Mas entendi!

Comment: Espero que tenha ajudado, qualquer coisa estou a disposição.

Comment: Eu adicionei uma resposta mais próxima do que eu precisava pois apenas teve a tua resposta. Apenas para contribuir um pouco mais com o tópico e ajudar também a outras pessoas. Mas agradeço a sua ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

A solução da dúvida era adicionar

```
use PDO
```

à classe `Base` conforme abaixo:

```
<?php

 namespace BASE;

 use PDO;

 abstract class Base {
...
```

PDO é uma classe também. Logo, mesmo sendo nativa, para que possa trazer retorno diferente de `0 ou 1`, e `True ou False`, precisará ser referenciada!